# Temperature without decimals. 21.01 > 21

Tags: javascript

I am looking to display the API temperature without any decimals. Where in the code am I suppose to use the solution?

The below returns the temperature with 2 decimals, e.g. 21.01 Celcius

```
currentTemp.innerHTML = `${weather.main.temp}`
```

I have tried `Math.round` and `toFixed(2)` but assume I have to implement this somewhere else in my code.

Comment: `${Math.round(weather.main.temp)}`

Comment: This question is unclear, it seems you have already found the solution to your own problem with `Math.round(weather.main.temp)`

Answer (score 1):

There are four options.

**floor it:**

```js
let temperature = 21.01;
console.log(Math.floor(temperature));
```

**convert to int:**

```js
let temperature = 21.01;
console.log(parseInt(temperature));
```

**round it(you already tried):**

```js
let temperature = 21.01;
console.log(Math.round(temperature));
```

**Use toFixed(you already tried):**

```js
let temperature = 21.01;
console.log(+(temperature).toFixed(0));
```

Comment: Because this is temperature, I think rounding would be better than flooring

Comment: Thanks but this: currentTemp.innerHTML = `${Math.round(weather.main.temp)}` still does not work. As I'm getting the temperature on a GET request, the above "let temperature = 21.01;
console.log(+(temperature).toFixed(0));" is prob not a solution either?